# Concat string with comma in Laravel Collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections

i have a situation here. i have a collection as below

```
Collection
Array:2
(
0 => 
  +"id": 26
  +"st_crime": "AMEAÇA CONTRA MENOR"
}
1 => 
  +"id": 26
  +"st_crime": "ARREBATAMENTO DE PRESO"
}
)
```

and i'd like to get an output like that below:

```
Collection
Array:1
(
0 => 
  +"id": 26
  +"st_crime": "AMEAÇA CONTRA MENOR, ARREBATAMENTO DE PRESO"
}
)
```

any help is welcome

Comment: lets see your code.

Comment: @Joseph_J I have no code yet. I have nothing in mind to inplement that. i know that using mysql group_concat function that could be simple. but i can't imagine how to implement that using php.

Comment: I was probably going to recommend concat.  To do this in php you will loop through your array and append st_crime when the ids match.

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but how about combining groupBy() and concat() collection methods.

Comment: I was facing problems because my DB is sql server 2016 and group_concat does not exist then i'm trying with php

Answer (score 1):

```
$col = collect([
    (object) ['id' => 26, 'st_crime' => 'AMEAÇA CONTRA MENOR'],
    (object) ['id' => 26, 'st_crime' => 'ARREBATAMENTO DE PRESO']
]);


$col->groupBy('id')->map(function ($group) {
    $struct = clone $group->first();

    $struct->st_crime = $group->pluck('st_crime')->implode(', ');

    return $struct;
});

// result

=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2980
 all: [
   26 => {#2983
     +"id": 26,
     +"st_crime": "AMEAÇA CONTRA MENOR, ARREBATAMENTO DE PRESO",
   },
 ],
}
```

Without looking into a more generalized way to do it, this would work for the specific need.

**Bonus:**

Using tappity-tap-tap-[`tap`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-tap):

```
$col->groupBy('id')->map(function ($group) {
    return tap(clone $group->first(), function ($item) use ($group) {
        $item->st_crime = $group->pluck('st_crime')->implode(', ');
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you @lagbox. i'm gonna try to adapt your example to my situation.